# Merging 2d and 3d numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have nwo np arrays:

A) A 3d array with the shape `(65341, 2, 82)`

B) A 2d array with the shape `(15, 82)`

I would like to combine A and B to create array C with the shape `(65341, 17, 82)`. `nstack`, `dstack`, and `vstack` all give me errors saying that the dimensions of the two arrays are different, and I am not sure how to reshape them properly.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Do you really understand how dimensions work? A and B have 10,717,154 elements altogether, C would have 91,085,354, where do the missing elements come from?

Comment: Perhaps I haven't understood this properly. Essentially what I want to do is add the same 15 elements in B to the equivalent 2 elements in A. I'm guessing that np.stack is of use here, but unsure how.

Comment: "Essentially what I want to do is" still non sense. Take a smaller example and explain to yourself, and then if you can to us how 'adding' a (3,4) array to a (5,2,4) array would give a (5,5,4) array, on a concrete example. [mre]

Comment: 'A' contains 65341 matrices with the shape (2, 82). I'm assuming that for each matrix you want to append the matrix B. you can do it by creating a new empty array 'C' with the shape (65341, 17, 82), setting the slice [:, :2, :] to 'A' and the slice [:, 2:, :] to 'B'.

Comment: @Julien _"where do the missing elements come from?"_  The beauty of Numpy is 60% in broadcasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say that the *semantics* of your

> I would like to combine A and B to create array C with the shape (65341, 17, 82)

is not completely clear to me, the closest thing that I'd devise is as follows; *syntactically speaking*, it's correct (see the shape of the result) but I cannot say if this is what you want… please let us know!

```
In [30]: import numpy as np
    ...: 
    ...: d0, d1a, d1b, d2 = 4, 3, 4, 2
    ...: a = np.arange(d0*d1a*d2).reshape((d0, d1a, d2))
    ...: b = np.arange(d1b*d2).reshape((d1b, d2))+d0*d1a*d2
    ...: # with ref. to help(np.concatenate) and help(np.broadcast_to)
    ...: c = np.concatenate((a,np.broadcast_to(b, (a.shape[0],*b.shape))), axis=1)
    ...: print('',a.shape, b.shape, c.shape, sep='\n')
    ...: print("\na\n%s"%a)
    ...: print("\nb\n%s"%b)
    ...: print("\nc\n%s"%c)

(4, 3, 2)
(4, 2)
(4, 7, 2)

a
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]]

 [[18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]]]

b
[[24 25]
 [26 27]
 [28 29]
 [30 31]]

c
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [24 25]
  [26 27]
  [28 29]
  [30 31]]

 [[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]
  [24 25]
  [26 27]
  [28 29]
  [30 31]]

 [[12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]
  [24 25]
  [26 27]
  [28 29]
  [30 31]]

 [[18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]
  [24 25]
  [26 27]
  [28 29]
  [30 31]]]

In [31]:
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was after! Thank you for an answer to what was admittedly an unclear question!

Comment: @Matt Oh well, I hit the spot!